# Facebook open graph: How to change story tense?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I created a custom story for my facebook app and I can make a basic story post using the facebook js sdk like this

```
FB.api(
   'https://graph.facebook.com/me/my_app_namespace:eat',
   'post',
   {apple: 'apple_url'},
   function(response) {
     alert('finished');
   }
);
```

However, the resulting post is in the past tense and the object is in the singular. For instance the resulting post is very similar to

```
John ate an apple
```

but the goal is to have the resulting post be

```
John is eating an apple
```

or

```
John is eating apples
```

I have looked through the facebook open graph documentation and I have found no information on how to change the action tenses and make the objects plural or singular. How can I change the resulting post?

Comment: Did you look into action `start_time` attribute? I never used that myself but I think it may indicate that this kind if action has timespan and then should have present continous tense

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I just had to use the expires_in setting to make the action present tense. Do you have any clue how I can use the plural form when I post as well?

Comment: You can't ;) Facebook uses plural form when there are couple of silimiar events in a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for reference:

If you want to make a facebook story to show up in present tense you should set the `expires_in` attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign a value to an expire_in attribute to the action. Most importantly, if you don't know when the event will end but can track it, leave the value blank and set up a callback to detect when the event is completed.

Then from your callback, assign a value of 0 to "expire_in." that will indicate to the Facebook SDK that the event is expired, and it will alter the tenses accordingly.